# How to query available item leases based on a date range in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, left-join, multiple-conditions

We have a business that rents out international phone numbers to customers when traveling. When a customer makes an order We want to display to the customer the available phone numbers for his booking dates based on his start_date and end_date and numbers which is not occupied yet.

Since these phone numbers are rented out, I need to select from the table ONLY those numbers that are not rented out yet for dates that would interfere with the current customers dates.

I also don't want to rent out any phone number prior to 7 days after its end date. Meaning, If a customer booked a phone number for 1-1-2020 through 1-20-2020, I don't want this phone number to be booked by another customer before 1-27-2020. I want the phone number to have a 7 day window of being clear.

I have a table with the phone numbers and a table with the orders that is related to the phone numbers table via phone_number_id. The orders table has the current customers start_date and end_date for travel without the phone number id saved yet to it. The orders table also has the start_date and end_date for all other customers dates of travel as well as which phone_number_id was assigned/booked up for their travel dates.

How would the **MySQL** query look like when trying to select the phone numbers that are available for the current customers dates?

I build below query at the moment

```
SELECT x.id
     , x.area_code
     , x.phone_number
     , y.start_date
     , y.end_date 
  FROM vir_num_table x
  LEFT 
  JOIN orderitemsdetail_table y
    ON y.vn_id = x.id 
 WHERE y.start_date BETWEEN '2020-01-11' AND '2020-01-18' 
    OR y.start_date IS NULL
```

I've build this query but stuck here how can I add end_date logic.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post your entire table schema, it will be very difficult to come up with a query without it.

Comment: query pattern to check for date overlap is frequently asked question on stackoverflow,  for some ideas, see   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388666/how-to-check-if-two-date-ranges-overlap-in-mysql/28389422#28389422   or   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535799/how-to-store-date-and-time-ranges-without-overlap-in-mysql/37536411#37536411

Comment: @RWri I've updated my query in my question. Can you please look and let me know if you need any other information then ?

Comment: Can we instead reject the premise of the question? A SELECT is unnecessary and (unless bound up within a transaction) counterproductive.

Comment: Incidentally, one of the joys of aliases is that they can be shorter than the thing they're aliasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I'd approach the problem would be to look at conceptually, is as a cross product of the set of all phone numbers, along with the reservation timeframe, and then exclude those where there's a conflicting reservation.

A conflict would be an overlap,  existing reservation that has a `start_date` *before* the *end* of the proposed reservation  AND  has an `end_date` *on or after* the *start* of the proposed reservation.

I'd do an anti-join pattern, something like this:

```
 SELECT pn.phone_number
   FROM phone_number pn

   LEFT
   JOIN reservation rs
     ON rs.phone_number  = pn.phone_number
    AND rs.start_dt     <= '2019-12-27' + INTERVAL +7 DAY
    AND rs.end_dt        > '2019-12-20' + INTERVAL -7 DAY
  WHERE rs.phone_number IS NULL
```

That essentially says get all rows from phone number, along with matching rows from reservations (rows that overlap), but then exclude all the rows that had a match, leaving just phone_number rows that did not have a match.

We can make the `<` test a `<=` or , subtract 8 days, to tailor the "7 day" window before; we can tweak as we run the query through the test cases,

We can achieve an equivalent result using a `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery. Some people find this easier to comprehend than the ant-join, but its essentially the same query, doing the same thing, get all rows from phone_number but exclude the rows where there is a matching (overlapping) row in reservation

```
 SELECT pn.phone_number
   FROM phone_number pn
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        ( SELECT 1 
            FROM reservation rs
           WHERE rs.phone_number  = pn.phone_number 
             AND rs.start_dt     <= '2019-12-27' + INTERVAL +7 DAY
             AND rs.end_dt        > '2019-12-20' + INTERVAL -7 DAY
        )
```

---

There are several questions on StackOverflow about checking for overlap, or no overlap, of date ranges.

See e.g.

[How to check if two date ranges overlap in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388666/how-to-check-if-two-date-ranges-overlap-in-mysql/28389422#28389422)

[PHP/SQL - How can I check if a date user input is in between an existing date range in my database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558263/php-sql-how-can-i-check-if-a-date-user-input-is-in-between-an-existing-date-ra/37558440#37558440)

[MySQL query to select distinct rows based on date range overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928840/mysql-query-to-select-distinct-rows-based-on-date-range-overlapping/36929666#36929666)

---

**EDIT**

Based on the SQL added as an edit to the question, I'd do the query like this:

```
SELECT pn.`id`
     , pn.`area_code`
     , pn.`phone_number`
  FROM `vir_num_table` pn
  LEFT
  JOIN `orderitemsdetail_table` rs
    ON rs.vn_id        = pn.id
   AND rs.start_date  <= '2020-01-18' + INTERVAL +7 DAY
   AND rs.end_date     > '2020-01-11' + INTERVAL -7 DAY
 WHERE rs.vn_id IS NULL
```

The two "tricky" parts.  First is the anti-join, understanding how that works.  (An outer join, to return all rows from `vir_num_table` but exclude any rows that have a matching row in reservations.  The second tricky part is checking for the overlap, coming up with the conditions: r.start <= p.end AND r.end >= p.start, then tweaking whether we want to include the equals as an overlap, and tweaking the extra seven days (easiest to me to just subtract the 7 days from the beginning of the proposed reservation)

... now occurs to me like we need to add a guard period of 7 days on the end of the reservation period as well, doh!

Comment: I used the query from this post, but my results aren't as expected. A number that is booked for 1/15/2019 - 1/18/2019 is coming back from my query that has dates of 1/16/2019 - 1/17/2109. Any suggestions what I am doing incorrect?

Comment: My issue was that I wasn't wrapping my dates in the query in single quotes! Maybe my mistake will help someone else:)

Comment: The sample SQL I posted has *not* been tested; my intent was to demonstrate a pattern, not necessarily deliver SQL ready-to-to.  Whatever query we come up with, needs to be tested, especially tests at boundary (is the "seven day" window what we expect.  This pattern makes no effort to identify which matches are optimal in terms of best fitting up against other reservations, attempting to leave other numbers with larger contiguous availability.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a query plus sorting algo to choose the optimal phone number selection for maximum utilization efficiency (i.e. getting as close as possible to exactly 7 days before and after each use).

I set it to give open ends a weight of 9, so that "near perfect" fits (7-8  days before or after) would be selected ahead of open-ended numbers.  This will yield a slight efficiency improvement, as open numbers can accommodate any reservation.  You can adjust this for your needs.  If you set this to 0, for example, it would always select open numbers first.

```
SELECT ph.phone_number,
    COALESCE(
        MIN(
            IF(res.end_date > res.start_date > '2020-01-18',
            NULL, -- ignore before-comparison for reservations starting and ending after date range
            DATEDIFF('2020-01-11', res.end_date)
        ), 9) AS open_days_before,
    COALESCE(
        MIN(
            IF(res.start_date < res.end_date < '2020-01-11',
            NULL, -- ignore after-comparison for reservations starting and ending before date range
            DATEDIFF(res.start_date, '2020-01-18')
        ), 9) AS open_days_after
FROM phone_number ph
LEFT JOIN reservation res
    ON res.phone_number = ph.phone_number
    AND res.end_date >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY
GROUP BY ph.phone_number
HAVING open_days_before >= 7
    AND open_days_after >= 7
ORDER BY open_days_before + open_days_after
LIMIT 1
```

Edit: updated to add grouping, because I realize this is an aggregate problem.

Edit 2: bug fix, changed `MAX` to `MIN`

Edit 3: added `res.end_date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 DAY` to ignore past reservations, limiting aggregate data and treating phone number with no reservations between 6 days ago and the beginning of the new order as "open on the front-end"

Edit 4: added IF conditions to eliminate reservations outside the given before-or-after comparison ranges (e.g. comparing reservations after the selected range from influencing the "open days before" number), to prevent negative numbers, except when there's overlap with the selected range.

Comment: what about a phone number where there aren't any reservations, where the outer join doesn't find a matching row. Seems like `open_days_before` is going to be `NULL`, and won't satisfy the condition in the `HAVING` clause. I do like the idea of ordering rows "weighed" based on best fit with existing reservations.

Comment: @spencer7593 that's what the `COALESCE` is for... it defaults to a value of `9` for open-ended numbers.

Comment: Somehow I glazed right over the COALESCE and the significance of the 9. My brain if futzing over doing the MIN() on the DATEDIFF, seems like this is going to omit rows where there's not an overlap, fitting into a gap with a reservation that ends before, and a reservation that starts after,  those DATEDIFF are going to return negative values ... just doesnt seem like this is going to get a match ... in a general case where we're fitting between two existing reservations ... i'm not going to be able to get my brain wrapped around this without me working through some test cases ...

Comment: @spencer7593 good point about the datediffs... I added an if condition to fix that, and also to prevent issues with overlapping date ranges.  I think that does it!

Comment: +10 I really like the idea of "weighting" the query results, by the size (number of days) of the gap at either end of the proposed reservation.  I'd be tempted to extend the query, and return those values; the downside is that it would make the query more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the info you've added then you shouldn't need to check the start date of phone numbers which have been booked out.

- You customer provides you with a start date and an end date.
- You only rent out phone numbers 7 days after their last lease ended

All you need to do is fetch back phone numbers which either:
- Are not rented out and therefor aren't in the orderitems table
- OR have an end_date which is 7 days before the new customer's start date.

Here you go:

```
    SELECT 
    `main_table`.`id`,
    `main_table`.`area_code`,
    `main_table`.`phone_number`,
    `orderitemsdetail_table`.`start_date`,
    `orderitemsdetail_table`.`end_date`
FROM
    `vir_num_table` AS `main_table`
        LEFT JOIN
    `orderitemsdetail_table` AS `orderitemsdetail_table` ON main_table.id = orderitemsdetail_table.vn_id
WHERE
    (DATE_ADD(orderitemsdetail_table.end_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY) < '<CUSTOMER START DATE>'
    AND orderitemsdetail_table.start_date > '<CUSTOMER END DATE>')

    OR orderitemsdetail_table.id IS NULL
```

Comment: You're missing the condition where a lease expired on a given number in the last 7 days.  E.g. lease expired yesterday, new reservation starts tomorrow. That's < 7 days between the last reservation and the new one.

Comment: Thanks answer edited, all we needed to do is add 7 days to our customer end date when comparing it to start dates in the orders table.